# integrate paypal in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I want to integrate PayPal simple Payment (by redirecting to PayPal and returning to our website after completion) gateway with my CakePHP website, any idea about available components or helpers? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this all works with a simple form. just use the form action as described (paypal website). i do not think that there is something that can be made simpler.

Comment: I was going to ask a the same here. Just a simpler form may not do the trick. How about if you have a controller Products and you want to acknowledge in the Db that Paypal transaction was a success, without manually going to Paypal. What is the best approach?

Comment: in paypal there is the option to send a server sided post to your app. this can be configured (via url) how ever you want it. eg. yourdomain.com/products/paypalcheck. with this url you could post all available payment information to your action paypalcheck and there you can to ckecks against sent data.

Comment: so there no need any cakephp paypal plugin?

Comment: @alexdd55 I'm using simple form from paypal website.Currently, it will accept the payment, and the payment gets processed ok, after payment, it just shows the standard PayPal 'Thank You' screen - there's no button to go back to my site, and it doesn't do it automatically.

What I'd like to happen is for it to accept the payment, and then return to my site to say 'thank you' there; And another question, after payment how to get response from paypal? thanks

Comment: @user559744 there is an option on paypal, that the customer should be send to the page. IMHO the paypal admin panel is a mess, so it is not easy to find. there is also a option to send a get command to your server that gives you the possibility register the payment without having the customersending back to your page.